# LINQ display previous date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a ms sql 2008 table with data from a weather datalogger.

table format

LogDate  (nvarchar) 01/04/2010
LogTime  (nvarchar)  10:00
LogMonth  (nvarchar)  APR
LogYear  (nvarchar)  2010
Rain_Today  (Double)  5.6

The daily reading for rain totals are at 08:59 the next day.  So the table shows 5.6 mm for example: 03/04/2010 at 08:59, but this is actually the total for the previous day i.e. 02/04/2010.  All the rain readings are a day out and the last day of the month's value is shown for the first day of the next month.

Is there a way to list the above rain values for the date 02/04/2010 instead of 03/04/2010? The date and time columns are in string format.  This code works fine but the dates are a day out as above.

**Edit Fixed the code from bitwise & to conditional &&**

```
var q = from c in context.Wxlogs
               where
               c.LogYear == year && c.LogMonth == month && c.Time.Contains("08:59")
               orderby c.LogDate                    
               select new {c.LogDate, c.Rain_today};
```

table data

Apr 2010    01/04/10    09:00   0.0
Apr 2010    01/04/10    09:01   0.0
Apr 2010    01/04/10    19:02   23.7
Apr 2010    02/04/10    00:03   23.8
Apr 2010    02/04/10    08:59   23.8  -- time of reading

Hope this makes sense.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks Belinda

Comment: This is were it would have been really beneficial had you stored your LogDate column as a DateTime and not just an nvarchar. Is there any reason you are not using the appropriate data types for your time /date related columns?

Comment: I think it was something to do with Entity Framework and some problems I had. It was initially DateTime and Date.  Would it be worth converting them back?

Comment: Yes you should definitely use the proper column types, your query then becomes doable using `SqlFunctions`

Comment: Working on changing the Date to DateTime, but it might take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work this one out!!  A new field LogDate2 was added and LogDate was converted from Nvarchar to a DateTime datatype and populated with LogDate's values.

As some LINQ functions aren't available using Entity Framework e.g. LogDate.Day or LogDate.Month I used EntityFunctions which provided the ability to use CLR methods.

See [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx)

So, the new code below works perfectly.  It may not be the best or most efficent way to do it, but it provides the correct results.

```
var q = from c in context.Wxlogs
               where
               c.LogYear == year && c.LogMonth == mm && c.LogTime.Contains("08:59")
               orderby c.LogDate2
                let dm = EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LogDate2, -1)
                select new {dm, c.Rain_today};
```

A big thanks to everyone who steered me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Before going further. The "AND" clause is wrong, you are using a bitwise operator.

it should be && and not &

OR is it just a TYPO?

```
var q = from c in context.Wxlogs
               where
               c.LogYear == year && c.LogMonth == month && c.Time.Contains("08:59")
               orderby c.LogDate                    
               select new {c.LogDate, c.Rain_today};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question. If so, please mark it as an answer so people do not spend time on it.

Comment: No, still have the original problem that the date is a day out.

Comment: Can you post some table values (Rows) here. You can add a condition of date to your where clause for e.g. c.LogDate == DateTime.Now.Date but this is not guaranteed if you are using a varchar.

Comment: e.g. Date 11/05/2010, time 08:59, sorry is that what you mean?

Comment: i meant the table rows. add some rows here to see the data. You can edit the post to include it

Comment: Actually the & operator for boolean types is the logical AND operator. In a normal context it works the same as the Conditional AND operator except that it doesn't short circuit. However linq to sql translates both of them to an AND clause so in this case there is no difference between the two.